# DIVs are not floating all the way to the left in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="width:560px">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; margin-bottom: 20px">
        <div style="float: left; width: 40%">
            <!-- Thumbnail -->
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 60%">
            <!-- Title -->
            <!-- Author -->
            <!-- Price -->
            <!-- Quantity -->
            <!-- Add to Cart -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like in `Chrome`:
[image]

But this is what it looks like in `Firefox`:
[image]

How can I get Firefox to display like Chrome?

Comment: just increase the height....now seriously... upload jsfiddle.

Comment: @RoyiNamir never used that before. I guess im missing out on something?

Comment: Your problem has something to with the elements height and/or bottom-margin/-padding…

Comment: ok :) jsfiddle.net/- is a way for you to put some sample html + js and ssave it on the web  - so other users can fix it and give you a new link. have fun.. feel free to ask me if you dont understand something about  it.... p.s. there is also jsbin.com. ( i prefer it)

Comment: @RoyiNamir That looks cool! Thanks. I'll do a bit of jsfiddling next time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Bedtime reading: [The 960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)

This is due to the height of the first element "pushing" the third element across in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Why that's happening, I don't know. It's a common problem when fixed height isn't used, which in my opinion is good practice too avoid, as you can *never* really tell how high something will be.

Could I suggest a slight workaround to the layout. It's slightly more manual, but would ensure a "row-like" layout. By simply adding a `row` div, it will allow you to ensure there are at least 2 items in a row, like so.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">Item 1...</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">Item 3...</div>
        <div class="item">Item 4...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">Item 5...</div>
        <div class="item">Item 6...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to "push" the new row starting, you'll want to clear both, on the `row` class.

**Pros:**

- There will always be 2 items in a row
- Items will always start level at the top

**Cons**

- Changing it to `x` items per row would require HTML changes

Answer (score 1):

You should always use a CSS reset. It helps to avoid these problem completely. One I personally use is this one:
http://html5reset.org/

Cheers,
Robin